# Go generics with type constraints: cannot use false (untyped bool constant) as T value in assignment

Tags: go, generics

I have the following piece of code:

```golang
func createGrid[T int | bool](size int, forFlooded bool) [][]T {
    var tempGrid [][]T

    for i := 0; i <= size+1; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= size+1; j++ {
            if forFlooded {
                tempGrid[i][j] = false
            } else {
                tempGrid[i][j] = -1
            }
        }
    }
    return tempGrid
}
```

I get the following errors on the lines where I'm assigning `tempGrid[i][j]`:

```sh
cannot use false (untyped bool constant) as T value in assignment
```

```sh
cannot use -1 (untyped int constant) as T value in assignment
```

This is how I'm using it:

```golang
var grid [][]int;
grid = createGrid(n, false);
var flooded [][]bool;
flooded = createGrid(n, true);
```

Here, I get `CannotInferTypeArgs` (`cannot infer T`) error.

I've also tried extracting that type constraint to an interface.
What am I doing wrong?

Update:

Taking @kraylog's suggestions, I solved it using this:

```golang
func initialiseGrid[T int | bool](size int, fn func(i, j, size int) T) [][]T {
    var tempGrid [][]T

    for i := 0; i <= size+1; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= size+1; j++ {
            tempGrid[i][j] = fn(i, j, size)
        }
    }
    return tempGrid
}
// In some function body:
grid := initialiseGrid(n, func(i, j, size int) int {
    if i == 0 || i == size+1 || j == 0 || j == size+1 {
        return -1
    } else {
        return int(math.Floor(rand.Float64() * 6))
    }
})
flooded := initialiseGrid(n, func(i, j, size int) bool { return false })
```

Comment: tempGrid[i][j] is either int or bool so one of tempGrid[i][j] = false or tempGrid[i][j] = -1 will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are a shortcut the compiler gives you for creating multiple instances of the same function, for different types.

Let's try to do the compiler's work manually. You'll get these two functions - one for int:

```
func createGridInt(size int, forFlooded bool) [][]int {
    var tempGrid [][]int

    for i := 0; i <= size+1; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= size+1; j++ {
            if forFlooded {
                tempGrid[i][j] = false
            } else {
                tempGrid[i][j] = -1
            }
        }
    }
    return tempGrid
}
```

and one for bool:

```
func createGridBool(size int, forFlooded bool) [][]bool {
    var tempGrid [][]bool

    for i := 0; i <= size+1; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= size+1; j++ {
            if forFlooded {
                tempGrid[i][j] = false
            } else {
                tempGrid[i][j] = -1
            }
        }
    }
    return tempGrid
}
```

Suddenly, this doesn't make sense anymore, since you can't assign `false` to `int` as in the first function, and the other way around in the second.

To solve the problem, you need to use `T` as the type you're working on. This also solves the code smell of passing a boolean flag to a function:

```
func createGrid[T int | bool](size int, fillWith T) [][]T {
    var tempGrid [][]T

    for i := 0; i <= size+1; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= size+1; j++ {
            tempGrid[i][j] = fillWith
        }
    }
    return tempGrid
}
```

And you can call this with:

```
createGrid(n, false)
createGrid(n, -1)
```

Comment: `To solve the problem, you need to use T as the type you're working on. This also solves the code smell of passing a boolean flag to a function.`

This is certainly helpful. Thank you. 

The thing is I'm initializing the grid with random integers when the boolean is false (I removed that logic before posting to SO). 

I ended up making two different functions as I think that is appropriate as you said. But just for my knowledge, are there conditional types or type guard/narrowing like in TS?

Comment: The generics system in Go is new and pretty limited (I think that's on purpose, as with most of Go). So things like narrowing don't exist. However, I don't think you need that in this case - you can make `fillWith` a function that returns `T` instead of a value.

Comment: Thanks again. I updated the question with what I implemented.